# Does symmetry and monotonicity in each argument of a function guarantees Schur Convexity?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, majorization

A [Schur Convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur-convex_function#Schur-Ostrowski_criterion) function defined on $(x_1,x_2)$ is one if it satisfies the following inequality:
$$(x_1-x_2)  (\frac{\partial}{\partial {x_1}}f -\frac{\partial}{\partial {x_2}}f) \ge 0, \quad \quad\text{for all } (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}.$$

**Question:**

If $f$ (all partial derivatives exist) is

- symmetric along line $x_1=x_2$,
- and $f$ is monotonic increasing (or decreasing) in each of its argument

then does it implies that f is **Schur concave (or Schur convex)** ?

Comment: We should also assume that $f$ is differentiable to begin with; if $q : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly positive, monotonically increasing function which is not continuous, then $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto q(x_1) q(x_2)$ satisfies the hypotheses but the desired partial derivatives don't exist.

Comment: you've confused the definition of a Schur Convex function with Schur's Criterion.  This mistake is very much the same as in the 1-d case when people erroneously state the 'definition' of a convex function to be on with a positive 2nd derivative.

Comment: I added the second missing inequality. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: No, the two inequalities you wrote are completely equivalent. @user8675309 is pointing out that this inequality is only equivalent to schur convexity when $f$ is differentiable and symmetric. So, in the context of your question, this inequality is what you want to show, but it's incorrect to say that this inequality is the definition of schur convexity.

Comment: Right. There would be only one inequality (as before) for a function defined on 2D domain.

Comment: @user8675309 Nop. I am not confusing. I know that for a multidimensional function to be Convex all the eigen values of its Hessian matrix must be non-negative. And for Schur convex function (though a misnomer, should be better called Schur monotonic whenever majorization condition on the domain is satisfied) there would be a set of inequalities (like in original question) to be satisfied for a multidimensional function to be Schur Convex.

Comment: Sorry that technically is wrong too. You really should be a lot more careful with definitions.  I very much agree with @diracdeltafunk here.

Comment: I understand that I should be more careful with definition. And inequality above is not the universal definition of Schur Convexity. But I ve used *if* and not *iff*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x,y) = (\arctan(x)  + \pi/2) (\arctan(y) + \pi/2)$$ Then $f$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, and monotonically increasing in each argument since $\arctan$ is positive and monotonically increasing. Now
$$(x-y)(f_x - f_y) = (x-y) \left(\frac{\arctan(y)+\frac{\pi }{2}}{x^2+1}-\frac{\arctan(x)+\frac{\pi }{2}}{y^2+1}\right)$$
is not everywhere-nonnegative. For example, setting $x = 1$, $y = -1$ yields $-\pi/2 < 0$. Thus, $f$ is not schur convex.

Edit: neither is this quantity everywhere-nonpositive! Setting $x = 0$, $y = -2$ yields $2 \left(\frac{2 \pi }{5}-\arctan(2)\right) \approx 0.3$.

Comment: $f$ is Schur Concave instead.

The criteria for Schur Concavity is everywhere non-positive for your $f$.

I should have mentioned it in my question; to imply both Schur Concavity or Schur Convexity (which I actually meant) to avoid confusion.
Anyways, thank you for taking your time and the example.

Comment: @kaka Thanks for clarifying. I don't know anything about schur concavity/convexity (I was just going off the definitions you provided), but you should take a look at the comment on your post, which seems to imply that you have the wrong definition!

Comment: I corrected the definition.

Comment: @kaka It seems like my example is not Schur concave either! Setting $x = 0$, $y = -2$ yields a positive number.

Comment: True. It looks like $f$ is Schur concave in first quadrant whereas Schur convex in third quadrant.